# Use while loop to print as many times as requested by user

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Hello I am stuck on a programming assignment for class. The assignment is to make a program that can count different loops. I have the prompt user input code correct I think I just can't figure out how to make it print my message the amount of times that I have entered.

I want the second while loop to print something like

Row 1 - Hello

Row 2 - Hello

Row 3 - Hello

Row 4 - Hello

For the number that I put as the input.

Thank you for the help in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountingLoops
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message; // First message prompt
        String inputString; // For reading input.
        double numRows; // Number to be asked.
        double rowNumber = 1;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the message you want to print? ");
        message = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20:" );
        numRows = keyboard.nextDouble();

        while (numRows > 20 || numRows < 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Number was not between 1-20. Try Again.");
            System.out.print("Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20: ");
            numRows = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        while (numRows <= 20)
        {
            System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber++ + " - " +  message);
            rowNumber = keyboard.nextDouble();
            rowNumber++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it currently doing? Anyway, your last loop is an infinite one as you're never updating the value of numRows

Comment: This what currently prints when i compile and run the program.

Enter the message you want to print? Hello
Enter how many times you want your message to be printed. Enter the value from 1-20:5
Row 1.0 - Hello

I want it to print 
Row 1.0 - Hello
Row 2.0 - Hello
Row 3.0 - Hello
etc. up until the amount entered for numRows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean by "a program that can count different loops". Currently the bottom while loop is an infinite loop since numRows isn't being updated. Here's what I believe can solve your issue:

```
while (numRows > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Row " + rowNumber++ + " - " +  message);
    rowNumber++;
    numRows--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an assignment, I won't provide the code. But all the problem with your code is in the last while loop.

First, you don't even change the value of the variable numRows and of course, you cannot exit the while loop.

Second, you don't need to read another input during this while loop since all the input is done at the beginning.

Third, you added rowNumber twice in your code and obviously, it is incorrect and it should be changed to something else.

Comment: I know its my last while loop messed up I'm just completely confused on how to make it print as many times as i input.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer will involve comparing rowNumber and numRows to determine when you are done.